# many to many laravel relation stock invoice

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to make a many to many relation in laravel for my invoice and products model and save them in a povet(junken) table  but i got stock at getting the relations and show them in front so here is the code

in my invoice model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','invoice_products','id','id');
}
```

in my product model

```
public function  invoice() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Invoice','invoice_products','id','id');
}
```

the migration of my invoice_products table

```
 Schema::create('invoice_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('invoice_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('product_quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
```

now in my controller i want to retrice all the invoices with the id of "1" that have the product id of "2" for example and i want to show them in view.

Comment: I guess you mean retrieve all invoices that have product with id = 2 ? also your mapping isn't look right `id , id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By viewing your migration  your mapping looks weird, It should be

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'invoice_products', 'invoice_id')
                    ->withPivot('quantity')
                    ->as('invoice_products_pivot');
    }
}


class Product extends Model
{
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoice_products', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Now to fetch all invoices who are linked with product id = 2 you could use `whereHas` filter

```
$product_id = 2;
$invoices= Invoice::whereHas('products', function ($query)use ($product_id) {
    $query->where('id', '=', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

To eager load products per invoice object you can use `with`

```
$product_id = 2;
$invoices= Invoice::with('products')->whereHas('products', function ($query)use ($product_id) {
    $query->where('id', '=', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

Comment: @M khalid junaid thanks again khalid your answer is full and clear as always :) but 1 more question i have is that naming convention of primary keys for example for products should i use id or product_id which was is more standard in laravel ??

Comment: The naming convention in my opinion should be readable like if there is a reference of product saved in `invoice_products` it should be called as `product_id` same goes for invoice reference `invoice_id`, `id` is commonly used for primary key notation so format for foreign key in a table would be like `referencedtable_pkcolumnofreferencedtable` like `product_id`

Comment: @m khalid junaid yes thats my question in my other tables for example product table should i have id or product_id as my primary key ??

Comment: @Farshad In products table primary key should be named as `id` for readability, `product_id` should be used in other table where you link your product table

Answer (score 1):

I think the query builder is

```
$invoice = \App\Invoice::findOrFail(1);
```

that query will find invoice data by id.

if you want to select specified id of product

```
$products = $invoice->products()->where('id', 2);

// this for getting pivot
$qty = $products->pivot->product_quantity
```

if you want to get all products from invoice

```
$products = $invoicce->products;
```

and that query will get products data by invoice that has been selected at first.